# Does the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} (x^2+4y^2)^{x^2y^2}$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I have to study the existence of$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} (x^2+4y^2)^{x^2y^2}$$
I've first considered the limit $$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x,mx) = \lim_{x\to 0} \ (x^2+4m^2x^2)^{m^2x^4} = e^{\lim_{x\to 0} m^2x^4\log(x^2+4m^2x^2)}$$

Using L'Hospital Rule, I get $$\lim_{x\to0}\ m^2x^4\log(x^2+4m^2x^2)=\lim_{x\to0}-\frac{m^2x^4}{2}=0$$
So $$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x,mx) = e^0 = 1$$
Now how can I compute the limit differently?

Comment: Try L'hopital  in the exponent. The limit should work out to be 1.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

We know that
$$\lim_{X\to0^+}X\ln(X)=0$$

thus
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}(x^2+4y^2)\ln(x^2+4y^2)=0$$

On the other hand
$$0\le \frac{x^2y^2}{x^2+4y^2}\le y^2$$

So,
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2+4y^2}=0$$

You will find that the limit is $ e^0=1$.